# Changing variable on another module for functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, import

I have made two py files, in which **main.py** contains:

```
import module

module.Print("This should not appear.")

module.Silence = False
module.Print("This should appear.")
```

The module imported is **module.py** which contains:

```
Silence = True


def Print(Input, Sil= Silence):
    if Sil == False:
        print(Input)
```

The expected result should be:

> This should appear

The result:

> 

Comment: You are not passing a second argument to your `Print` method. So it is always taking the default argument you defined as `False`. When you call `Print` just pass your second argument: `module.Print('stuff', module.Silence)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you've defined your `Print` function with a default argument of True (since `Silent == True` when this module is imported, and the function created).  Changing the module variable, `Silent` to False later isn't going to affect this function definition in any way.  It's already set in stone.

You could achieve what it looks like you want to doing something like (in `module.py`):

```
Silence = [True]

def Print(Input, Sil= Silence):
    if Sil[0] == False:
        print(Input)
```

...

And then setting `module.Silence[0] = False` in `main.py`.

[I'm assuming the goal here was to call the function *without* passing in an explicit `Sil` argument.  You can certainly just pass in an explicit second argument and have the function perform exactly how you expect instead]

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a function with a default setting that can be dynamically changed. This will use the global `Silence` only if the `sil` argument is omitted in `Print()` function call.

```
def Print(input, sil=None):
    if sil is None:
        sil = Silence
    if not sil:
        print(input)
```